# Factorial with while loop in C

Tags: c

Hello friendly community,
i´m really new in coding and also here registred on stackoverflow, so excuse me when I ask such simple questions. I lack the understanding to understand why this code does not work, because even after compiling no error message appears.
My Code below shows my try to code a while loop, calculating the factioral and printing the total:

```
#include <stdio.h>

/*      Factorial 5! = 5*4*3*2*1      */

main ()
{
    int Wert;
    int fak = 1;

    scanf ("%d", Wert);

    while ( Wert > fak) {
        fak = fak * Wert;
        Wert = Wert - 1;
        printf ("%d", fak);
    }
}
```

It should calculate the factorial after input of a number and print the total. Maybe this can´t work but i don´t understand the why.
Thank you for your time.

Comment: Define *does not work*

Comment: `while ( Wert > fak) {` ==> `while ( Wert > 1) {`

Comment: `scanf ("%d", Wert);` ==> `scanf ("%d", &Wert);`. Also, the compiler output here: https://ideone.com/hGPAb3 shows you the problem.

Comment: Are you sure the compiler didn't give any diagnostics for that code ? If not, you should probably switch to a better one.

Comment: Also, a code using 32-bit `int` is only good up to 12! after then it overflows.

Comment: Would a `for` loop be better?

Comment: I tried it with a FOR loop. Here the code: #include <stdio.h>

main()
{
    int value;
    int fac; 
    
    scanf ("%d", &value);

    for ( fac = 1; fac = fac * value; value = value - 1)    {
        printf ("%d", fac);
    }

}  /* When i type 5 i should get "120" as a result, but the result is "52060120120"  Can anyone explain and fix the result?*/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, `scanf` expects the address of `Wert`, not its value, and also update your `while` loop to compare with `1`. Here's the fixed version:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int Wert;
    int fak = 1;

    scanf ("%d", &Wert);

    while ( Wert > 1 ) {
        fak = fak * Wert;
        Wert = Wert - 1;
    }
    printf ("%d", fak);
}
```

Input:

```
5
```

Output:

```
120
```

But since factorials easily overflow integers, it may be a better idea to use `double` instead:

```
#include <stdio.h>

double fact(double d)
{
    if (d < 1.0)
        return 1.0;
    return d * fact(d - 1.0);
}

int main(void)
{
    double d = 0;
    if (scanf("%lf", &d) != 1) {
        perror("Failed to read stdin");
        return -1;
    }
    printf("%lf! = %lf", d, fact(d));
    return 0;
}
```

Input:

```
100
```

Output:

```
100.000000! = 93326215443944102000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000.000000
```

Just keep in mind that [floating point math is broken](https://stackoverflow.com/q/588004/10147399).